# vim: unable to match character after new line properly

Tags: vim

In vim, I'm trying to match all lines that has `^A.` but not followed by a `B.` on the next line.
I'm matching it with `/\v^A\. .*$\n[^B]`.
This correctly identifies the relevant portion in question 2., but not in question 3.  I'm not able to figure out why.  The ending matches `\n\n`. And `[^B]` should match `\n` but it doesn't.  What am I doing wrong?

```
1. Hello?
A. aaaaaaaa
B. bbbbbb
C. ccccccc
D. ddddd

2. Hello?
A. aaaaaaaa B. bbbbbb
C. ccccccc
D. ddddd


3. Hello?
A. aaaaaaaa B. bbbbbb C. ccccccc D. ddddd

4. Hello?
```

Comment: It's an empty line, so you probably must match `([^B]|$)`

Comment: that seems to work.  But doesn't [^B] also match the $?

Comment: no it doesn't. Otherwise your Hello line would also have to match `^Hello?[^a][^b][^c][^d]` etc, does not make any sense

Comment: I don't get it.  [^B] says any thing but capital B.  And $ != B. Is that not valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [`:help /[\n]`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5B%5Cn%5D) documents, a collection like `[^B]` does not match an end-of-line character.

> This makes it Vi compatible: Without the "_" or "\n" the collection does not match an end-of-line.

You have two options: Either explicitly include a newline, so that your line followed by an empty line also matches:

```
/\v^A\. .*$\n([^B]|$)/
```

Or do a *negative lookahead* match with [`/\@!`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%21):

```
/\v^A\. .*$\nB@!/
```

Comment: The things I don't know about vim!